# How can I place an image/or video inside of a glass plane?

Tags: modeling, mesh, image, video, glass

[image]

https://pasteall.org/blend/e7a874e519cf471d9c9626d9bba5e34c

To expand upon the title, I have created a plane and used the Glass BSDF on it. I then made another plane and placed it inside of the glass, this plane has the image/or video on it. Now it does seem to work, however, the image/or video plane end up being semi transparent. How can I get it to display the image plane without losing opacity.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe create 2 objects, one (opaque) for the video image, and the other one for your glass?

Comment: Would be interesting to know how you created the material of the video plane since if I understood it correctly, it's different from the glass plane. If you didn't use a _Glass BSDF_, _Transparent BSDF_ or maybe a _Principled BSDF_ with a _Transmission_ value > 0 than most of the shaders are usually opaque - well, most of them, I'm not going to list all shaders and their possibilities of being opaque or not here ;) So the question is what material do you use for the plane that is or appears to be semi-transparent?

Comment: @RDJ456 Hm, an Emission shader should be fully opaque when plugged into the material output - you're using the _Surface_ output, not the _Volume_? Maybe you could add a screenshot to your question to demonstrate how this semi-transparent plane looks? Or maybe upload the file and place the link in the question: https://pasteall.org/blend/ (the plane objects and the materials should be sufficient, I don't think we need the video itself)

Comment: @RDJ456 Is this really semi-transparent or is it just a reflection in the glass? The only thing looking semi-transparent that I can see is the border of the cylinder in the background, but: if I look at a glass plane in the correct angle, the reflection could match to what lies in the background. Did you change the angle? Have you put something behind it to see if it can also be seen through the plane? Is the video plane very close to the glass so that it could be Z-fighting (the surfaces rivaling which shows up front)? If nothing of that is causing it, maybe the file would be helpful, too.

Comment: @RDJ456 Please don't vandalize your posts. If the question is no longer relevant for you it may still be useful to future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to ignore my suggestions for some tests to try and see if it is really transparent or just a reflection. For example, putting some other object behind the glass plane to see if it's also visible and not just the cylinder which would imply it's a reflection.

So I set up a different material for the cylinder, making it glow red in front of the glass and blue behind the glass. I also put a glowing white sphere behind the glass plane to see if if shines thorugh. This is the model setup:

[image: model setup]

And this is the resulting render. You can clearly see that the cylinder on the glass plane visible "through" the image is red, which means it's a reflection of the red part in front, not  the blue part behind shining through. Also the glowing white sphere is not visible at all through the image. So there is no transparency.

[image: render]

By the way, your models are a mess. There is no scale applied (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply* > *Scale*) which is why you need a higher bevel amount and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to round the edges of the glass plane. Also the bevel segments of 60 are ridiculously high, I wouldn't go higher than 6. If you want smooth edges, right-click on the object and choose *Shade Smooth*. Then enable *Auto Smooth* in the *Object Data Properties*. The *Subdivision Surface* is completely obsolete for a simple plane.

And just a quick comparison: if you would make the glass much thicker, the refraction would have a stronger effect and the difference between reflection and refraction from what is behind the glass becomes more distinguishable.

[image: strong refraction]

Comment: @RDJ456 Lost your interest in the solution?

Comment: The problem is, you want to retain the clear glossy look of the glass, so this means you have to keep the reflections - otherwise it wouldn't look glossy.